# How to copy file in the server to another folder with putty

Tags: linux, bash, putty

I would like to copy or move some file `a.xml` from `/tmp` to another folder in the same server `/var/lib/myfolder`.

I tried the following with putty:

```
user@server:/tmp$ mv a.xml /var/lib/myfolder
```

I get the error message, that this operation is not allowed.

How can I copy or move this file to another folder?

**Update:**

Error message:

> mv a.xml is not possible: The operation is not allowed

Comment: maybe you dont have permissions then. Try with sudo or acquire the permissions

Comment: Try posting the error message as well.

Comment: I have updated the error message

Comment: as the first comment, you could this command: `sudo mv a.xml /var/lib/myfolder`

Comment: Well :-) I've wrote the same answer on the end of this page, please mark it as answered :-)

Comment: The question and answers have nothing to do with putty.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cp` and then `rm` the source file.

```
cp a.xml /var/lib/myfolder
rm -f a.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to, as my comment, write this command:

```
sudo mv a.xml /var/lib/myfolder
```